Serialization Not working for CMapWordToOb class in MFC
I am trying to test serialization in MFC, and currently I am stuck at this class CMapWordToOb. I have tried one unit test case to serialize and then deserialize the map, but getting abort window during run time.
Has anyone tried serialization for CMapWordtoOb, and if it works for them?
I am trying to test void CMapWordToOb::Serialize(CArchive& ar).
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <afxtempl.h> 
#include <afx.h>     
#include <iostream>

class CAge : public CObject {
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CAge)
public:
    CAge() {}
    CAge(int age) {
        m_age = age;
    }
    int getAge() const {
        return m_age;
    }
private:
    int m_age;
};


bool CompareMaps(const CMapWordToOb& map1, const CMapWordToOb& map2) {
    // Check if the maps have the same count of elements
    if (map1.GetCount() != map2.GetCount()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Iterate through all elements in the first map
    POSITION pos = map1.GetStartPosition();
    CAge* pa1, * pa2;
    WORD key1, key2;
    for (pos = map1.GetStartPosition(); pos != NULL;) {
        map1.GetNextAssoc(pos, key1, (CObject*&)pa1);

        // Check if the key exists in the second map
        if (!map2.Lookup(key1, (CObject*&)pa2)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check if the values are the same
        if (pa1->getAge() != pa2->getAge()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


// Function to print the contents of a CMapWordToOb object
void PrintMap(const CMapWordToOb& map) {
    std::cout << "MapWordtoOb: ";
    POSITION pos = map.GetStartPosition();
    CAge *pa;
    WORD key;
    for (pos = map.GetStartPosition(); pos != NULL;)
    {
        map.GetNextAssoc(pos, key, (CObject *&)pa);
        std::cout << key << " : " << pa->getAge() << std::endl;
    }
}


// Test case for serializing and deserializing CMapWordtoOb
void TestSerializeCMapWordtoOb() {
    std::cout << "..........Start Of Test Cases for CMapWordtoOb Serialization.........." << std::endl;
    CMapWordToOb map;
    map.SetAt(3, new CAge(20));
    map.SetAt(4, new CAge(30));
    map.SetAt(2, new CAge(40));

    std::cout << "CMap created" << std::endl;
    // Serialize the map
    CFile file(_T("mapData.dat"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
    CArchive arStore(&file, CArchive::store);
    map.Serialize(arStore); //crashing here
    arStore.Close();
    file.Close();

    // Deserialize the map from file
    CMapWordToOb deserializedMap;
    CFile deserializedFile(_T("mapData.dat"), CFile::modeRead);
    CArchive arLoad(&deserializedFile, CArchive::load);
    deserializedMap.Serialize(arLoad);
    arLoad.Close();
    deserializedFile.Close();

    std::cout << "Deserialized ";
    PrintMap(deserializedMap);

    // Compare the original map with the deserialized one
    if (CompareMaps(deserializedMap, map)) {
        std::cout << "Unit test passed: Serialization and deserialization successful." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Unit test failed: Serialization and deserialization failed." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "..........End Of Test Cases for CMapWordtoOb Serialization.........." << std::endl;
}

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CAge, CObject, 1);

int main() {
    TestSerializeCMapWordtoOb();
    return 0;
}


//crashing here - What does "crash" mean to you? Please describe the error as accurately as possible. Include error diagnostics where available.

@IInspectable the error window, when we run the program.
(Popup window): "Deubg error!" abort() has been called. Please retry to debug the application.  with 3 options : abort, retry, ignore.

Show the dialog, either as a screenshot or by pressing Ctrl+C and pasting the text version here. Next, press "Debug" so that the debugger takes you to the code that caused the failure, and paste it here as well.

Why on earth people are using CMapWordToOb and classes alike in 2024? I am mind blown!

@sergiol most likely legacy software

You forgot to implement the Serialize method in your CAge class.
The MFC framework has no knowledge of your CAge class and therefore it cannot serialize a CAge object. It's up to you to implement the CAge::Serialize method that takes care of the serialisation/deserialization of a CAge object.
Add this to your CAge class definition:
void Serialize(CArchive& ar);

And add this implementation:
void CAge::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    CObject::Serialize(ar);

    if (ar.IsStoring())
        ar << m_age;
    else
        ar >> m_age;
}

This is explained in details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/serialization-making-a-serializable-class.
The general documenation about MFC serialization is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/serialization-in-mfc.
Also worth reading:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1176939/All-About-MFC-Serialization
